# OpenStreetMap basemap in QGIS that shows the Pacific in the middle

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, openstreetmap, basemap

I have a researcher looking for a basemap like OpenStreetMap, but showing the Pacific at the center. They want to overlay the Ring of Fire, and then show the Out-of-Africa migration.

The migration part can probably be done in any image editing software, once the overlays are done. Can this be done in something like QGIS?

Answer (score 3):

It's perfectly possibly and easy to do: set the project CRS to `EPSG:3832`: a Pacific centered equivalent of the regular WebMap CRS `EPSG:3857`.

*To change the project CRS, click on the bottom right corner, filter for `3832` and select `WGS 84 / PDC Mercator - EPSG:3832`*:
[image]