# Getting continuous map extent using QGIS

Tags: qgis, extents, basemap, antimeridian

All the basemaps on my QGIS stop just to the east of New Zealand.

Is there any way I can make the extent continuous (basically restart from the other side)?

[image]

Comment: Try [EPSG:3832](https://epsg.io/3832)

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/459132/88814 or https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/397580/88814

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to use [EPSG:3832](https://epsg.io/3832) as a CRS.